# modal form leaves my screen blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, modal-dialog

You have the following modal form that executes a POST method of my controller

[image: modal]

my view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="agregarProducto">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"> 

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="myForm">
                    <label>Agregar Cantidad</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idcheckcantidad" />                        
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cantidad" id="idcantidad" disabled="disabled"  />                      
                    <label>Codigo Producto</label> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoproducto" id="idcodigoproducto" autofocus="true" />
                </form>               

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Agregar Material" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the javascript that executes the post method is the following...

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {              
                var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Despachos/AgregarProducto",
                    data: myformdata,
                    success: function () {                     
                        $("#agregarProducto").modal("hide");                      
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
```

the problem is that when I finish executing the Agregar Producto method my screen is blocked and it is dark

[image: screenshot]

my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AgregarProducto(int codigoproducto, int? cantidad)
    {          
            //CONSULTO LOS PRODUCTOS QUE EXISTEN EN EL DETALLE
            var despachotmp = db.DespachoDetalleTmps.Where(o => o.Email == User.Identity.Name && o.Kn_CodigoProducto == codigoproducto).FirstOrDefault();

            if (despachotmp == null)
            {
                //BUSCO EL PRODUCTO
                var producto = db.Productoes.Find(codigoproducto);

                if (producto == null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "Debe Seleccionar un Producto o Material Válido";
                    return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }

                if (cantidad == null)
                {
                    despachotmp = new DespachoDetalleTmp
                    {
                        v_Nombre = producto.v_Nombre,
                        Kn_CodigoProducto = producto.Kn_CodigoProducto,
                        Email = User.Identity.Name,
                        d_Cantidad = 1,
                    };

                    db.DespachoDetalleTmps.Add(despachotmp);

                }

                if (cantidad != null)
                {
                    despachotmp = new DespachoDetalleTmp
                    {
                        v_Nombre = producto.v_Nombre,
                        Kn_CodigoProducto = producto.Kn_CodigoProducto,
                        Email = User.Identity.Name,
                        d_Cantidad = Convert.ToInt16(cantidad),
                    };

                    db.DespachoDetalleTmps.Add(despachotmp);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (cantidad == 0)
                {
                    despachotmp.d_Cantidad += 1;
                    db.Entry(despachotmp).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                if (cantidad != 0)
                {
                    despachotmp.d_Cantidad += Convert.ToInt16(cantidad);
                    db.Entry(despachotmp).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }                      
            db.SaveChangesAsync();               
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I get this behavior?
any help for me?

Comment: You are handling a submit button and making both an ajax post a normal post (you have mot cancelled the default submit). The whole point of an ajax call is to **stay on the same page** and ajax calls cannot redirect so your `return RedirectToAction()` code in the POST method makes no sense

Comment: the method calls me forces to return "something" @StephenMuecke

Comment: What is the point of this? You are sending back a whole lot of html that you never use! Just return `null` or a `JsonResult` if you want to stay in the same page (but you need to cancel the default submit if you want to stay on the same page - `$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ....`

Comment: I am getting the same behavior returning null and attaching its javascript code ... is not encouraged to propose a clear answer? @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of your script. You can use the below code to close the modal.

```
$("#agregarProducto").hide();
```

You can follow the below code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {              
                var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Despachos/AgregarProducto",
                    data: myformdata,
                    success: function () {                     
                        $("#agregarProducto").hide();                      
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Try this code. Good Luck!

Comment: Can you please explain it what is the difference?

Comment: You can use the below code to close the modal.

$("#agregarProducto").hide();

Comment: As far as I know there is no method like $("#agregarProducto").modal("hide");  Unless you are using a plugin which has defined a modal() method, this is wrong. If you want to hide the #agregarProducto you should do it as said in the answer, because hide() is an actual method in jQuery. Good Luck

Comment: the problem is not hiding the modal, the problem is that when I hide my screen it shows dark ... I'm not sure how this behavior is explained, no response proposed works for me @VigneshVS

Answer (score 0):

It looks like model is not clissing properly,

Try below options to close it

```
$('#modal').modal('toggle');
```

or

```
$('#modal').modal().hide();
```

should work.

But if nothing else works you can call the modal close button directly:

```
$("#modal .close").click()
```

Comment: your answer did not help my problem, try all your methods several times ... thanks for exposing the differences between the methods. @programtreasures

Answer (score 0):

try these for best practices:

```
//OPEND
$('#modal').modal('show');
//HIDE
$('#modal').modal('hide');
```